# How to natural sort “X-Y” string data, first by X and then by Y?

Tags: mysql, sql, natural-sort

Given this data:

```
W18-40461
W19-1040
W20-4617
W20-100
```

I've tried several of the common natural sorting methods for mysql, but they won't sort these  in a natural descending way, like:

```
W20-4617
W20-100
W19-1040
W18-40461
```

For example:

```
select theID 
from Table 
where theID 
order by lpad(theID, 9, 0) desc
```

Comment: what result did you want to get?

Comment: I think you want to use `RPAD` instead of `LPAD`.

Comment: Is the prefix (before the hyphen) always three characters?

Comment: How should W55-66 and W55-7 be sorted? Is the right of the dash to be sorted as an integer? That is, **is the ordering 7 < 66, or '66' < '7'?** The left-of-dash data shown won’t have this potential issue *iff* it has a fixed width such as YY through 2099..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the parts on either side of the `-` are limited to 2 digits and 5 digits respectively, you can extract the two numeric values using `SUBSTR` (and `LOCATE` to find the `-` between the two numbers) and then `LPAD` to pad each of those values out to 2 and 5 digits to allow them to be sorted numerically:

```
SELECT *
FROM data
ORDER BY LPAD(SUBSTR(id, 2, LOCATE('-', id) - 2), 2, '0') DESC,
         LPAD(SUBSTR(id, LOCATE('-', id) + 1), 5, '0') DESC
```

Output (for my expanded sample):

```
id
W20-12457
W20-4617
W20-100
W19-1040
W18-40461
W4-2017
```

[Demo on db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nLHYmhBcvEmHDCCGcUMmmT/2)

If the values can have more than 2 or 5 digits respectively, just change the second parameters to `LPAD` to suit.

Answer (score 1):

I would do this as:

```
order by substring_index(col, '-', 1) desc,
         substring_index(col, '-', -1) + 0 desc
```

This orders by the part before the hyphen as a string.  And it converts the part after the hyphen to a number for sorting purposes.

Comment: If there could be a single digit number before the `-`, this could sort out of order e.g. `W4` will sort higher than `W20` instead of lower.